# See if thread is running in flask web application

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, openshift

Hi I'm just learning python, threading and flask

what is the proper way to see thread is running in flask app ? I already tried storing the thread in global variable

```
global thread_a
thread_a = threading.start()
```

and tried using flask.current_app

```
flask.current_app.thread_a = threading.start()
```

then I check if thread is running using

```
thread_a.is_alive()
```

it is works fine on my local machine. however when I deploy to remote server (this case is openshift) the value of the variable is sometimes defined but sometimes not, so I thought this method doesn't always work ?

Comment: What version of OpenShift? What WSGI server are you using to host the Flask application? What is the reason for creating background threads? Usually creating your own background threads in a web application is a bad idea and an indication of a poor design.

Comment: I use openshift online v2 using default server, I guess it is Apache Mod_WSGI. The reason is I want to do some long calculation and not keep the user waiting with blank page, is there alternative other than creating background threads ?

Comment: The problem you are having is that on OpenShift 2 the WSGI server configuration is mutli process, so a subsequent request may not go back to the same process. BTW, you may want to start looking at the OpenShift 3 version of OpenShift online as OpenShift 2 will in time be retired. It is easier in OpenShift 3 to control what WSGI server is started and thus you can control whether is a multi process server configuration.

Comment: Ah it is clear then, thanks. I will look into openshift 3 then. could you post as answer maybe ? so I'll mark this as answered ?